# Storing and retrieving bandwidth objects in nonparametric regression

Tags: r, regression

I nonparametrically estimate a conditional density using `R`s `np` package (Racine & Hayfield).

It is quite time-consuming (~20 minutes for my actual example, not the reproducible one below) to estimate the bandwidth. Hence, before illustrating just the final results in class, I want to precompute the bandwidth object, store it and retrieve it in class.

I think of something like this, without success:

```
library(np)

# some artificial data
n <- 100
y <- rnorm(n)
X1 <- rnorm(n)
X2 <- rnorm(n)

# nonparametric regression
bw <- npcdensbw(y ~ X1+X2, bwmethod="cv.ls")
fhat <- npcdens(bws=bw)

save(bw,file="bandwidth.Rdata") # saves something, but...

# ...this does not work
rm(list=ls())
bw <- load("bandwidth.Rdata")
fhat <- npcdens(bws=bw)
```

Comment: Just use `load("bandwidth.Rdata")` without assign it to a variable bw <- . The name of the object will be the one you used at `save`

Comment: embarrassingly simple...thanks!